main.jsx:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined - React + Vite + Relay
I am running into the following error trying to get my React application working with Vite. It also uses Relay and React (and Flow)
main.jsx:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main.jsx:3:11

The code this is referring to is the following
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

I feel like I have tried so many different configurations that I can't remember, but currently I have the following:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import babel from 'vite-plugin-babel';
import relay from "vite-plugin-relay";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    relay,
    react(),
    babel({
      babelConfig: {
        babelrc: false,
        configFile: false,
        plugins: [
          "babel-plugin-syntax-hermes-parser",
          "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"
        ],
        parserOpts: { flow: "all" },
        presets: [
          "@babel/preset-env", 
          "@babel/preset-react",
          "@babel/preset-flow"
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
})

It has been challenging to understand when I change something whether its a step forward, or a step back, so any advice on how to improve my approach of this would be extremely beneficial.
The codebase is currently using Relay and Flow, so it is not viable to move away from these easily atm.
Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "...",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.2.2",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vite ",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^16.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-hermes-parser": "^0.21.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^9.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ft-flow": "^3.0.9",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "flow-bin": "^0.236.0",
    "flow-remove-types": "^2.236.0",
    "flow-typed": "^4.0.0",
    "get-graphql-schema": "^2.1.2",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "hermes-eslint": "^0.21.1",
    "relay-compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "relay-devtools": "^1.4.0",
    "relay-hooks": "^9.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.11",
    "vite-plugin-babel": "^1.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-relay": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "formik": "^2.4.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-relay": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  }
}

Let me know if there would be other valuable details to update this with

...is the problem in your compiled output or in your actual source? You aren't actually showing us any of the code producing the error

@JaredSmith good callout and my apologies. I updated to reflect this is happening in the entrypoint (but essentially everywhere)

@Abbas - this is using Flow, not Typescript

The relay configuration needs to be set to use module not commonjs.
Add
"eagerEsModules": true

to relay.config.json
... with vite it seemed to not work with relay.config.js for me so I had to make it json file and then in package.json use script to specify run the relay-compiler with the location of the relay config
relay.config.json should look something like:
    {
      "src": "./src",
      "language": "javascript",
      "schema": "./schema.graphql",
      "eagerEsModules": true,
      "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/**",
        "**/__mocks__/**",
        "**/__generated__/**"
      ]
    }

